# How to Approve Instagram Api Permissions for Android App

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I have just completed development of an Android Application that uses Instagram Api to show followers, following and who unfolllowed. The Api is in Sandbox Mode at till now and I want to submit the application to Instagram for permissions (follower_list, basic) approval. But submission page shows options just for website. 
How can I submit Android Application for approval?

[image]

"website" is highlighted in the image.

Comment: can you please share some more info about what you are getting?

Comment: @DeepPatel I have added the developers page screen shot. Please check.

Comment: I'm working for unfollowers method too. Are you get the permissions for your app? Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you must make a screencast(record your mobile app working).
I think you need put the company website url or if your app is on production environment on Google Play Store, so put the download link.
You can learn more [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)